# Can I legally refer to Maneuvers under the OGL?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat-maneuver, intellectual-property, ogl

The Battle Master subclass is not in the Systems Reference Document. I am designing a Wild West supplement for d&d-5e, to be published on DriveThruRPG, and I want to add a few Gun-Themed maneuvers that can be applied when firing a gun. Can I legally say “If you have access to maneuvers, the following maneuvers are added to the list of maneuvers available to you.”, and then list maneuvers that refer to superiority dice?

I cannot figure out if this would be considered a violation of product identity or not.

Comment: Related (perhaps dupes): "[Is referencing non SRD material permisable under the OGL 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181444)" and "[Does referencing non-SRD material by name constitute "use"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110077)" and "[Can artificer subclasses be in (third-party) material published under the OGL?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/188840)" and "[Can I sell a supplement that references non-SRD Cleric Domains?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167244)" and "[Does referencing specific monster actions break the 5e SRD/OGL?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/194860)"

Comment: Should we provide legal advise? We may be rules lawyers, but you might want to get a real lawyer for that.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin I'd recommend looking at the questions I linked above. We certainly field these type of questions and are more likely do have dealt with this kind of thing than most other Stacks. You'll note some of those answers are from actual lawyers and others start with "I Am Not A Lawyer". I wouldn't say we have to provide legal advice here, or, at the very least, we can do exactly what we did on those related questions (this question, as far as I can tell, is almost identical)

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin See [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5564/62294) for the answer to your question.

Comment: @Exempt-Medic I don’t believe that any of those answer mine. One refers to referencing book acronyms and page numbers, one is specific to referencing names of features (but not content), one is about publishing entire subclasses verbatim in homebrew, and the last is specific to monsters.

Comment: @TheDragonOfFlame, I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but would it be a reasonable compromise to build your maneuvers into a "fighting style" with similar (but legally distinct) rules to maneuvers? Similar enough that a reasonable DM would merge the "Deadeye Die" (you can have that one for free) with the "Superiority Die".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Probably not, but talk to a lawyer.

As written in [the OGL 1.0a](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/SRD-OGL_V1.1.pdf), the current license, this comes down to whether "maneuvers" count as product identity. Publishing under the OGL grants some permissions and incurs some restrictions in a way that's somewhat incongruous with normal copyright/trademark laws; "maneuver" isn't protected in those aspects (and likely couldn't be), but agreeing to the license adds some strictures.

Starting with the limitations on the use of product identity:

> Use of Product Identity: You agree not to Use any
> Product Identity, **including as an indication as to
> compatibility,** except as expressly licensed in
> another, independent Agreement with the owner of
> each element of that Product Identity. [...]

If "maneuvers" are product identity, given that they do not appear in the SRD, you would not be permitted to use them or reference them, including but not limited to just indicating that you have new maneuvers that are compatible. Product identity is defined fairly broadly under the OGL:

> "Product Identity" means product and
> product line names, logos and identifying marks
> including trade dress; [...] **names and descriptions** of
> characters, spells, enchantments, personalities,
> teams, personas, likenesses and **special abilities**;
> places, locations, environments, creatures,
> equipment, magical or supernatural abilities or
> effects, logos, symbols, or graphic designs; and any
> other trademark or registered trademark clearly
> identified as Product identity by the owner of the
> Product Identity, and which specifically excludes the
> Open Game Content

There's no exhaustive list of what is or isn't product identity published by WotC which leaves this in a bit of a grey area, but as the OGL calls out "names and descriptions of [...] special abilities" as being product identity, my read is that maneuvers count as product identity. This would mean that you can neither use nor refer to maneuvers in content published under OGL (as long as "maneuver" is clearly referring to 5e maneuvers — use as a general term, not referring to the special ability, ought to be fine), with various hazy middle grounds. Anything more specific is likely the purview of an actual lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for noticing those! In my look-overs of the OGL, I missed the line about "indication as to compatibility". I think the only grey area would be that "manuever" is a standard English word and not just a game term...

Answer (score -4):

No. If it isn't in the SRD, you can't use it.

> In the open gaming movement, a System Reference Document is a reference for a role-playing game's mechanics licensed under the Open Game License to allow other publishers to make material compatible with that game [Wikipedia Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Reference_Document)

So if WoTC didn't put it in the SRD it's protected under their copyright.

Comment: Comments deleted, as they're clearly not going to have any impact on what OP feels should be in the post.